# Why object is created using apt.Cache rather than apt.cache.Cache()

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, apt

i'm stucked at a point and i can't progress, sorry for this silly question. I searched a lot for that but i couldn't know what i am missing. Please help me.

I studied modules and classes in python. Now i want to make some operations using python and apt. I'm studying from : http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.cache.html
However, i couldn't understand, the module is apt.cache, as shown in the top of the page. I expected that object should be created by writing apt.cache.Cache(), but object is created by writing apt.Cache(), as shown below. Why?

```
    import apt
    import apt.progress

    # First of all, open the cache
    cache = apt.Cache()
    # Now, lets update the package list
    cache.update()
    # We need to re-open the cache because it needs to read the package list
    cache.open(None)
    # Now we can do the same as 'apt-get upgrade' does
    cache.upgrade()
    # or we can play 'apt-get dist-upgrade'
    cache.upgrade(True)
    # Q: Why does nothing happen?
    # A: You forgot to call commit()!
    cache.commit(apt.progress.TextFetchProgress(),
                 apt.progress.InstallProgress())
```

Second similar question is about below code, Cache class is imported from module apt.cache. I expected that object would be created by writing apt.cache.Cache(), but it is created by writing apt.Cache(). Why?

```
    >>> from apt.cache import FilteredCache, Cache, MarkedChangesFilter
    >>> cache = apt.Cache()
    >>> changed = apt.FilteredCache(cache)
    >>> changed.set_filter(MarkedChangesFilter())
    >>> print len(changed) == len(cache.get_changes()) # Both need to have same length
    True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check apt/__init__.py file - maybe it is an import alias?

Comment: There is nothing special in this file. Check that file from there : https://github.com/jolicloud/python-apt/blob/master/apt/__init__.py

Comment: See line https://github.com/jolicloud/python-apt/blob/master/apt/__init__.py#L26  and `__all__` exports. Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa , OK. I understand why apt.Cache is used in the first code i mentioned. However, in the second code, there are 2 mistakes i think. second and third rows are wrong, and they should be : cache=Cache() and changed = FilteredCache(cache)   , it think. Can you please check that rows whether i'm right or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `__init__.py` file of the apt [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), you see the line:

```
__all__ = ['Cache', 'Cdrom', 'Package']
```

The python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) says:

> The import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s
>   __ init__.py code defines a list named **all**, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import
>   * is encountered.

That's the reason why you can use `apt.Cache()`

For the second part of your question you can import directly the Cache class with

```
from apt.cache import Cache
cache = Cache()
```

You can also import the Cache class with

```
import apt
cache = apt.Cache()       //because of the __all__ variable in __init__.py
cache = apt.cache.Cache() //because it's a fully qualified name
```

Comment: `from apt.cache import Cache` doesn't permit what you say as it only binds one name `Cache`.

Comment: @DanD. I modified my answer to take your remark into account.